# Python append replaces the existing list with None

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures, append

Please have a look at this program.

The append function replaces the list with None. The error is attached below

```
class Solution(object):
     def isIsomorphic(self, a, b):

        ad = {} 
        bd = {}
        if len(a) != len(b):
             return False 
        for i in range(len(a)):
             if a[i] in ad:
                 ad[a[i]] = ad[a[i]].append(i)  
            else:
                ad[a[i]] = [i]

            if b[i] in bd:
                 bd[b[i]] = bd[b[i]].append(i)           
            else:
                 bd[b[i]] = [i]
         ret = True 
         for j,k in zip(ad.values(), bd.values()):
             if j != k:
                return False 
         return ret 


sol = Solution()
print sol.isIsomorphic("ccc", "aab")
```

ERROR

```
     ad[a[i]] = ad[a[i]].append(i)

 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: you were assigning ad[a[i]].append[i] to ad[a[i]] which was not needed. It's function call and returns None. You just need to do ad[a[i]].append(i)

```
class Solution(object):
 def isIsomorphic(self, a, b):

    ad = {} 
    bd = {}
    if len(a) != len(b):
         return False 
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] in ad:
             ad[a[i]].append(i)  
        else:
            ad[a[i]] = [i]


        if b[i] in bd:
             bd[b[i]].append(i)           
        else:
             bd[b[i]] = [i]
    ret = True 
    for j,k in zip(ad.values(), bd.values()):
        if j != k:
            return False 
    return ret
```

sol = Solution()
print sol.isIsomorphic("ccc", "aab")

Answer (score 1):

`append` appends the value to the list in place and returns `None`. So `ad[a[i]] = ad[a[i]].append(i)` means you're replacing `ad[a[i]]` with `None`.

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html) is the part of documentation that states it

> You might have noticed that methods like insert, remove or sort that
>   only modify the list have no return value printed – they return the
>   default None. [1] This is a design principle for all mutable data
>   structures in Python.