# Python object (list) seems to lose its type

Tags: python

In the code below, it says it cannot append "a" because it is class NoneType but just before that line, it is able to print the list and print its type. Why does it lose its type on the next line?

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
def output_list_of_feature_names(degree, list_of_feature_names):
    a = ["as", "asd"]
    for i in range(1, degree + 1):
        for item in combinations_with_replacement(list_of_feature_names, r = i):
            print(a)
            print(type(a))
            print(a)
            a = a.append(item)
    
    return a

output_list_of_feature_names(2, ["throttle", "angle", "final_vert_speed"])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python append replaces the existing list with None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741139/python-append-replaces-the-existing-list-with-none)

Answer (score 1):

```py
a = a.append(item)
```

is the offending line. a.append is a function that modifies the list in-place and returns None. That return value is then assigned to `a`.

To fix, change to:

```py
a.append(item)
```